# Reading Excel file(specifically Date of birth) using Java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read Date of birth from an excel file using java, But the problem is that, the input consist of value "14/7/1993" but my code results in the output "1900-04-14".
here is my code

```
String getDate(XSSFRow row, int index)
{

    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(index);
    cell.setCellType(2); // Formula Type

    Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();

    DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String result = dateformat.format(date);
    System.out.println("date: "+result);
    return "'"+result+"'";
}
```

Comment: If the `cell` contains a formula, you might well need to [evaluate it](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html).

Comment: It might be useful to see what the excel looks like. Does Excel consider this as a date?